# App crashes on uploading documents from Recents and WhatsApp Document folder on android 11

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am making a doctor and patient app in which I have added the document upload option but in android 11 device when I try to upload any pdf from "recents and WhatsApp documents" folder the app crashes (I get a null pointer exception for URI). If I upload it from downloads or somewhere else it works fine.
This is the code to show dialog to upload document:

```
    public void ShowFileDialog(Context context) {
    if (customDialog != null && customDialog.isShowing())
        customDialog.dismiss();
    customDialog = new Dialog(context, R.style.CustomDialogTheme);
    customDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    customDialog.setCancelable(false);
    customDialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_upload_dialog);
    customDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
    customDialog.getWindow().getAttributes().windowAnimations = R.style.DialogAnimation;
    customDialog.setOnKeyListener(new Dialog.OnKeyListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onKey(DialogInterface arg0, int keyCode,
                             KeyEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
                customDialog.dismiss();
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
    ImageView cancel = customDialog.findViewById(R.id.cancel);
    View camera = customDialog.findViewById(R.id.camera);
    View file = customDialog.findViewById(R.id.file);

    cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            customDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    camera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            customDialog.dismiss();
            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
        }
    });

    file.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            openFile(File_REQUEST);
        }
    });

    customDialog.show();

}
```

This is the openFile() function:

```
    private void openFile(int CODE) {
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    i.setType("*/*");
    startActivityForResult(i, CODE);
}
```

This in onActivityResult function:

```
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // do somthing...
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (customDialog != null && customDialog.isShowing())
        customDialog.dismiss();
    if (requestCode == File_REQUEST && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        Uri Fpath = data.getData();
        String path = FilePath.getPath(this, Fpath);
        File file = new File(path);
        int file_size = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(file.length() / 1024));
        if (file_size > 2048) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Your file size is too large", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Log.e("File path", path);
            String extension = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf("/"));
            Log.e("File Extension", extension);
            String base64 = encodeFileToBase64Binary(file);
            Log.e("File path", base64);
            documents.clear();
            uploadDocument(base64, extension);
        }
    }
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
        byte[] byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
        String encoded = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
        String currentDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
        documents.clear();
        uploadDocument(encoded, "image" + currentDate + ".png");
    }

}
```

This is convertToBase64 method

```
    private String encodeFileToBase64Binary(File yourFile) {
    int size = (int) yourFile.length();
    byte[] bytes = new byte[size];
    try {
        BufferedInputStream buf = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(yourFile));
        buf.read(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
        buf.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String encoded = Base64.encodeToString(bytes, Base64.NO_WRAP);
    return encoded;
}
```

This is FilePath class:

```
public class FilePath {
private static Uri contentUri = null;

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public static String getPath(final Context context, final Uri uri) {
    // check here to KITKAT or new version
    final boolean isKitKat = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT;
    String selection = null;
    String[] selectionArgs = null;
    // DocumentProvider
    if (isKitKat && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)) {
        // ExternalStorageProvider
        if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
            final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final String[] split = docId.split(":");
            final String type = split[0];

            String fullPath = getPathFromExtSD(split);
            if (fullPath != "") {
                return fullPath;
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        }

        // DownloadsProvider
        else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                final String id;
                Cursor cursor = null;
                try {
                    cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, new String[]{MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME}, null, null, null);
                    if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                        String fileName = cursor.getString(0);
                        String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/Download/" + fileName;
                        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(path)) {
                            return path;
                        }
                    }
                } finally {
                    if (cursor != null)
                        cursor.close();
                }
                id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(id)) {
                    if (id.startsWith("raw:")) {
                        return id.replaceFirst("raw:", "");
                    }
                    String[] contentUriPrefixesToTry = new String[]{
                            "content://downloads/public_downloads",
                            "content://downloads/my_downloads"
                    };
                    for (String contentUriPrefix : contentUriPrefixesToTry) {
                        try {
                            final Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Uri.parse(contentUriPrefix), Long.valueOf(id));

                     /*   final Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                                Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), Long.valueOf(id));*/

                            return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null);
                        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                            //In Android 8 and Android P the id is not a number
                            return uri.getPath().replaceFirst("^/document/raw:", "").replaceFirst("^raw:", "");
                        }
                    }


                }

            } else {
                final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final boolean isOreo = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O;
                if (id.startsWith("raw:")) {
                    return id.replaceFirst("raw:", "");
                }
                try {
                    contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                            Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), Long.valueOf(id));

                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                if (contentUri != null) {
                    return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null);
                }
            }


        }
        // MediaProvider
        else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
            final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final String[] split = docId.split(":");
            final String type = split[0];

            Uri contentUri = null;

            if ("image".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            } else if ("video".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            } else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            }
            selection = "_id=?";
            selectionArgs = new String[]{split[1]};


            return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, selection,
                    selectionArgs);
        } else if (isGoogleDriveUri(uri)) {
            return getDriveFilePath(uri, context);
        }
    }


    // MediaStore (and general)
    else if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {

        if (isGooglePhotosUri(uri)) {
            return uri.getLastPathSegment();
        }

        if (isGoogleDriveUri(uri)) {
            return getDriveFilePath(uri, context);
        }
        if( Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
        {
            // return getFilePathFromURI(context,uri);
            return getMediaFilePathForN(uri, context);
            // return getRealPathFromURI(context,uri);
        }else
        {

            return getDataColumn(context, uri, null, null);
        }


    }
    // File
    else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
        return uri.getPath();
    }

    return null;
}

/**
 * Check if a file exists on device
 *
 * @param filePath The absolute file path
 */
private static boolean fileExists(String filePath) {
    File file = new File(filePath);

    return file.exists();
}


/**
 * Get full file path from external storage
 *
 * @param pathData The storage type and the relative path
 */
private static String getPathFromExtSD(String[] pathData) {
    final String type = pathData[0];
    final String relativePath = "/" + pathData[1];
    String fullPath = "";

    // on my Sony devices (4.4.4 & 5.1.1), `type` is a dynamic string
    // something like "71F8-2C0A", some kind of unique id per storage
    // don't know any API that can get the root path of that storage based on its id.
    //
    // so no "primary" type, but let the check here for other devices
    if ("primary".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
        fullPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + relativePath;
        if (fileExists(fullPath)) {
            return fullPath;
        }
    }

    // Environment.isExternalStorageRemovable() is `true` for external and internal storage
    // so we cannot relay on it.
    //
    // instead, for each possible path, check if file exists
    // we'll start with secondary storage as this could be our (physically) removable sd card
    fullPath = System.getenv("SECONDARY_STORAGE") + relativePath;
    if (fileExists(fullPath)) {
        return fullPath;
    }

    fullPath = System.getenv("EXTERNAL_STORAGE") + relativePath;
    if (fileExists(fullPath)) {
        return fullPath;
    }

    return fullPath;
}

private static String getDriveFilePath(Uri uri, Context context) {
    Uri returnUri = uri;
    Cursor returnCursor = context.getContentResolver().query(returnUri, null, null, null, null);
    /*
     * Get the column indexes of the data in the Cursor,
     *     * move to the first row in the Cursor, get the data,
     *     * and display it.
     * */
    int nameIndex = returnCursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME);
    int sizeIndex = returnCursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.SIZE);
    returnCursor.moveToFirst();
    String name = (returnCursor.getString(nameIndex));
    String size = (Long.toString(returnCursor.getLong(sizeIndex)));
    File file = new File(context.getCacheDir(), name);
    try {
        InputStream inputStream = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        int read = 0;
        int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
        int bytesAvailable = inputStream.available();

        //int bufferSize = 1024;
        int bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);

        final byte[] buffers = new byte[bufferSize];
        while ((read = inputStream.read(buffers)) != -1) {
            outputStream.write(buffers, 0, read);
        }
        Log.e("File Size", "Size " + file.length());
        inputStream.close();
        outputStream.close();
        Log.e("File Path", "Path " + file.getPath());
        Log.e("File Size", "Size " + file.length());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Exception", e.getMessage());
    }
    return file.getPath();
}

private static String getMediaFilePathForN(Uri uri, Context context) {
    Uri returnUri = uri;
    Cursor returnCursor = context.getContentResolver().query(returnUri, null, null, null, null);
    /*
     * Get the column indexes of the data in the Cursor,
     *     * move to the first row in the Cursor, get the data,
     *     * and display it.
     * */
    int nameIndex = returnCursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME);
    int sizeIndex = returnCursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.SIZE);
    returnCursor.moveToFirst();
    String name = (returnCursor.getString(nameIndex));
    String size = (Long.toString(returnCursor.getLong(sizeIndex)));
    File file = new File(context.getFilesDir(), name);
    try {
        InputStream inputStream = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        int read = 0;
        int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
        int bytesAvailable = inputStream.available();

        //int bufferSize = 1024;
        int bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);

        final byte[] buffers = new byte[bufferSize];
        while ((read = inputStream.read(buffers)) != -1) {
            outputStream.write(buffers, 0, read);
        }
        Log.e("File Size", "Size " + file.length());
        inputStream.close();
        outputStream.close();
        Log.e("File Path", "Path " + file.getPath());
        Log.e("File Size", "Size " + file.length());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Exception", e.getMessage());
    }
    return file.getPath();
}


private static String getDataColumn(Context context, Uri uri,
                                    String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
    Cursor cursor = null;
    final String column = "_data";
    final String[] projection = {column};

    try {
        cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection,
                selection, selectionArgs, null);

        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            final int index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column);
            return cursor.getString(index);
        }
    } finally {
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.close();
    }

    return null;
}

/**
 * @param uri - The Uri to check.
 * @return - Whether the Uri authority is ExternalStorageProvider.
 */
private static boolean isExternalStorageDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.externalstorage.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}

/**
 * @param uri - The Uri to check.
 * @return - Whether the Uri authority is DownloadsProvider.
 */
private static boolean isDownloadsDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.providers.downloads.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}

/**
 * @param uri - The Uri to check.
 * @return - Whether the Uri authority is MediaProvider.
 */
private static boolean isMediaDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.providers.media.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}

/**
 * @param uri - The Uri to check.
 * @return - Whether the Uri authority is Google Photos.
 */
private static boolean isGooglePhotosUri(Uri uri) {
    return "com.google.android.apps.photos.content".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}


/**
 * @param uri The Uri to check.
 * @return Whether the Uri authority is Google Drive.
 */
private static boolean isGoogleDriveUri(Uri uri) {
    return "com.google.android.apps.docs.storage".equals(uri.getAuthority()) || "com.google.android.apps.docs.storage.legacy".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}
```

This is the log message I receive:

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1000, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/document:61752 flg=0x1 }} to activity {com.dronvideo.app/com.dronvideo.app.Activities.AppointmentDocuments}: java.lang.NullPointerException: uri
    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:5213)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:5254)
    at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:51)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2246)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:233)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8010)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:631)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:978)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: uri
    at java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:245)
    at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:1169)
    at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:1126)
    at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:1082)
    at com.dronvideo.app.Helper.FilePath.getDataColumn(FilePath.java:305)
    at com.dronvideo.app.Helper.FilePath.getPath(FilePath.java:128)
    at com.dronvideo.app.Activities.AppointmentDocuments.onActivityResult(AppointmentDocuments.java:182)
    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:8316)
```

Any help will be appreciated. I have tried many solutions but not able to fix this crash. Thankyou in advance. Images are uploading okay tho

Comment: `java.lang.NullPointerException` . What a terrible amount of irtelevant code you dumped here.

Comment: Your getPath() function can return null. And it does. But you are ignoring it.

Comment: Yes the problem is with the path and I am trying to fix it. Sorry I am kinda new here so I might have posted irrelevant code.

Comment: Delete `FilePath` and use the `Uri` correctly. Use `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()` to get an `InputStream` on the content identified by the `Uri`.

Comment: Tried it still no success